# Java WebSocketStompClient connect not returning

Tags: java, spring, stomp, spring-websocket

I'm trying to set up a simple application using Spring and websockets and have problem setting up the connection.
I have looked around for examples but almost all searches lead to the chat sample which is not what I am trying to do.
My app is a task/monitoring scenario. I want to be able to send a request to the server and then monitor the progress
of the task on the same connection.

I have seen the chat sample, portfolio sample and various other comments on SO but I'm not sure what I'm missing.
I'm new to Spring and websockets.

The logging appears to show a successful connection for the /info path but then the call to stompClient.connect() fails to return.

```
14:02:26.330 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.RestTemplateXhrTransport - Executing SockJS Info request, url=http://localhost:9080/Vault713MQServer/websocket/info
14:02:26.480 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Created GET request for "http://localhost:9080/Vault713MQServer/websocket/info"
14:02:26.559 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - GET request for "http://localhost:9080/Vault713MQServer/websocket/info" resulted in 200 (OK)
14:02:26.578 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.WebSocketTransport - Starting WebSocket session url=ws://localhost:9080/Vault713MQServer/websocket/369/ee89fc87489842af868c0f0452aacf13/websocket
14:02:26.578 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.socket.client.standard.StandardWebSocketClient - Connecting to ws://localhost:9080/Vault713MQServer/websocket/369/ee89fc87489842af868c0f0452aacf13/websocket
14:02:26.693 [WebSocketClient-AsyncIO-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.WebSocketClientSockJsSession - Processing SockJS open frame in WebSocketClientSockJsSession[id='ee89fc87489842af868c0f0452aacf13, url=ws://localhost:9080/Vault713MQServer/websocket]
14:02:26.693 [WebSocketClient-AsyncIO-1] DEBUG org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.DefaultStompSession - Connection established in session id=07e2d0cc-6f99-95d5-7014-614aad3e0f13
```

If I connect to 'http://localhost:9080/Vault713MQServer/websocket/info' in a browser it returns:

```
{"entropy":1894449220,"origins":["*:*"],"cookie_needed":true,"websocket":true}
```

On the server side I have:

```
/* WebSocketConfig.java */

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer
{
    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.addHandler(myHandler(), "/websocket").withSockJS();
    }

    @Bean
    public ServerHandler myHandler()
    {
        return new ServerHandler();
    }
}

/* ServerHandler.java */

public class ServerHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler
{

    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseStatus status) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Connection clodes with websocket server: session id {0}", session.getId());
        super.afterConnectionClosed(session, status);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Connected user with websocket server: session id {0}", session.getId());
        super.afterConnectionEstablished(session);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(WebSocketSession session, WebSocketMessage<?> message) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.handleMessage(session, message);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleTransportError(WebSocketSession session, Throwable exception) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.handleTransportError(session, exception);
    }
}
```

On the client side I have:

```
/* Clientside - Vault713MQClient.java */

public class Vault713MQClient
{
    static public class MyStompSessionHandler
        extends StompSessionHandlerAdapter
    {
        private String userId;

        public MyStompSessionHandler(String userId)
        {
            this.userId = userId;
        }

        private void showHeaders(StompHeaders headers)
        {
            for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> e : headers.entrySet())
            {
                System.err.print("  " + e.getKey() + ": ");
                boolean first = true;
                for (String v : e.getValue())
                {
                    if (!first)
                    {
                        System.err.print(", ");
                    }
                    System.err.print(v);
                    first = false;
                }
                System.err.println();
            }
        }

        private void sendJsonMessage(StompSession session)
        {
            session.send("/websocket", "hello from spring");
        }

        private void subscribeTopic(String topic, StompSession session)
        {
            session.subscribe(topic, new StompFrameHandler()
            {

                @Override
                public Type getPayloadType(StompHeaders headers)
                {
                    return String.class;
                }

                @Override
                public void handleFrame(StompHeaders headers,
                    Object payload)
                {
                    System.err.println(payload.toString());
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void afterConnected(StompSession session,
            StompHeaders connectedHeaders)
        {
            System.err.println("Connected! Headers:");
            showHeaders(connectedHeaders);

//          subscribeTopic("/topic/messages", session);
//          sendJsonMessage(session);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        WebSocketClient simpleWebSocketClient = new StandardWebSocketClient();
        List<Transport> transports = new ArrayList<>(1);
        transports.add(new WebSocketTransport(simpleWebSocketClient));

        SockJsClient sockJsClient = new SockJsClient(transports);
        WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(sockJsClient);
        stompClient.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());

        String url = "ws://localhost:9080/Vault713MQServer/websocket";
        String userId = "spring-" + ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 99);
        StompSessionHandler sessionHandler = new MyStompSessionHandler(userId);
        StompSession session = stompClient.connect(url, sessionHandler).get();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        for (;;)
        {
            System.out.print(userId + " >> ");
            System.out.flush();
            String line = in.readLine();
            if (line == null)
            {
                break;
            }
            if (line.length() == 0)
            {
                continue;
            }
            session.send("/websocket", line);
//          ClientMessage msg = new ClientMessage(userId, line);
//          session.send("/app/chat/java", msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone see what I have done wrong or does anyone have a simple complete example of what I am trying to do?

Many thanks.
KCM